# How can I extract predictions results after multiclass training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am trying to do some multiclass image classification with VGG-style, but unfortunately, I cannot reach my goal, and I think I have a stupid mistake in my code.

I have almost 16K images with 4 categories, let's say `1,2,3 and 4`. With the following code, I import all the images. I don't want to write for each category in order not to make a huge post. 4 times lines like this:

```
path_101 = ("/media/data/working_dir/categories/101/")
train_101 = []
for png in os.listdir(path_101):
    imageread = img.imread(path_101+png)
    imageread = cv2.resize(imageread, (320,240)) #resizing
    train_101.append(imageread)
```

After I concatenate them into one `x_data` variable.

```
x_data = np.concatenate((train_101, train_102, train_104, train_105), axis=0)
```

Following to this, I create my categorical data and do One Hot encoding:

```
# We create our classify data. 
one = np.ones(len(train_101))
four = np.ones(len(train_104)) +3
two = np.ones(len(train_102)) + 1
five = np.ones(len(train_105)) + 4

y = np.concatenate((one, two, four, five), axis= 0).reshape(-1,1)

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
labels=OneHotEncoder(categories = "auto", handle_unknown = "ignore")
y=labels.fit_transform(y).toarray()
```

And after these all I do the training part as you can see below:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_data, y, test_size = 0.2)
# import Keras and layers libraries
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPool2D , Flatten

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(240,320,3),filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=512,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(units=64, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(units=4, activation="softmax"))
model.add(Dense(units=4, activation="softmax"))

from keras.optimizers import Adam
opt = Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt , loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, verbose=1, epochs=5, validation_split=0.2)

results = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=64)
```

After I was having terrible results like 25% of accuracy. And for each epoch it was not changing. I taught that maybe my training output is not going well. I try to predict every 100th image of my initial db with this code:

```
prs=[]
for k in np.arange(1,15000,100):
    imgg=x_data[k]
    imgg=imgg[np.newaxis,...]
    pr=model.predict_classes(imgg)
    prs.append(pr[0])
print(prs)
```

And I was getting only 0s, or 2s depending on the class that has more input images. So something was wrong with it.

I am new in Neural Networks and maybe I did some amateur stuff.
How can I have class `0`, if my y data was one-hot encoded `1,2,4 and 5`?
I was thinking about the y variable, if I trained with one-hot encoding, maybe I should decode for predictions or what?

Thanks in advance! Do not hesitate to ask for details

Comment: Why do you have two softmax layers?

Comment: @xdurch0 thanks for your comment. I read it in one post here, that for categorical data of more than 2 classes it's necessary to have 2 layers.

Comment: First of all, you always need to perform some pre-processing into your input data e.g. normalization or scaling. So, the first few steps in neural networks are to analyze and process your input data. I suggest you, read some stuff more about Supervised Learning, OneHot Encoding and Pre-processing data, see libraries like `pandas`. T When you understand how things work; try to start with simpler tasks like "iris-classification" there are a lot of good tutorials about it.

Comment: @mcskinner I think you are confusing some terminology here. Softmax is correct. See [multiclass vs multilabel](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11859/what-is-the-difference-between-multiclass-and-multilabel-problem) -- you are thinking of multilabel.

Comment: @xdurch0 you are correct. I deleted my comment.

Comment: @AzatAleksanyan not sure where you read this, but that is wrong. You are almost certainly messing up the learning dynamics of your network. Remove one of the softmax layers and see if that helps. There might be other problems (e.g. with the one-hot encoding), but this is defnitely an issue.

Comment: Dear @xdurch0, really I appreciate your advice and readiness to help. I deleted the second softmax but had no improvement. 
From the comments above, I would like to mention that I am trying to predict positions of the horse. But anyway, answer at least this, if I train images and one-hot `y`, what will do `model.predict_classes`, one-hot output?